# Excel: how to group and then sort groups in a custom order?

Tags: excel, sorting, grouping

I have a table of data, I want to group this data and then sort the groups of rows in a custom way.

Example:
I have a table of data like this:

```
key   | group
-------------
BC.AA |  BC
AA.AA |  AA
CC.DE |  CC
AA.CD |  AA
```

And a list of groups like this

```
group | no. of items
-------------------
BC    |  1
CC    |  1
AA    |  2
```

How do I create a new table where the rows of the first table are grouped *and* ordered in the same way the second table is ordered. So like this:

```
key   | group
-------------
BC.AA |  BC
CC.DE |  CC
AA.CD |  AA
AA.AA |  AA
```

I like to do this with excel formulas, so it updates automatically when the original table is changed. I hope to avoid using macros, but I could write a custom excel worksheet formula.

Comment: Thanks! That's how I generated the group names. The problem with a custom sort order is that it doesn't scale well. I need to make lots of these lists and new groups will be added regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a column to your first table of `=MATCH(B1, GroupSheet!A:A)`, which will just return the corresponding row in `GroupSheet` that matches your group column, and sort by that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Excel 2010 by selecting the data you want to sort, going to the Data tab, clicking the Sort icon and then choosing Custom List... under Order.  This will be fine for small sorts, but you might need something more powerful for longer lists...